# Estimating progress of SymPy functions

Tags: python, sympy

I have issued a `sympy` command to solve some equation or another.  It's been a couple of days now, and I have no idea when to expect it to be finished.

Can I get `sympy` to log the progress of a call to, say, `.solvers.solve`?  If not, how can I estimate the worst-case time that `sympy` will need to solve some set of equations?

e.g.

```
import sympy, sympy.solvers
from sympy import sqrt

a,c,d,e,f,x = tuple(map(sympy.Symbol, 'acdefx'))

# when will this finish?
print(sympy.solvers.solve(
    3*sqrt((16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2 + (-8*a**2*c*x - 2*a*e + 2*a*x + 2*a*sqrt(16*a**2*c**2*
x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2) + d)**2)**3/(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2)**3)*(a*(2*c
*(8*a**2*c*x + 2*a*e - 2*a*x - d) - (4*a*c - 1)*sqrt(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2))*(-8*a**2*c*x - 2*a*e + 2*a
*x + 2*a*sqrt(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2) + d) + c*(8*a**2*c*x + 2*a*e - 2*a*x - d)*sqrt(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 +
 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2))*(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2)/((a*(4*a*c - 1)*(16*a**2*c**
2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2) - c*(8*a**2*c*x + 2*a*e - 2*a*x - d)**2)*(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*
d*x - 4*c*f + e**2 + (-8*a**2*c*x - 2*a*e + 2*a*x + 2*a*sqrt(16*a**2*c**2*x**2 + 8*a*c*e*x - 4*a*c*x**2 - 4*c*d*x - 4*c*f + e**2) + d)**2))
,x))
```

Comment: The solution to this equation is the x coordinate of the vertex of a parabola (ax^2 + 4acxy + cy^2 + dx + ey + f = 0).  There certainly exists a simple(ish) solution.  Of course, that doesn't imply that it will be found, but it definitely exists, and has a relatively simple formulation in a,c,d,e and f (Since formulae from e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042028/axis-of-symmetry-for-a-general-parabola/2042048#2042048) could accomplish this same task much more simply...)

Comment: "It's probably stuck in an infinite loop"... Is this something that can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy does not provide any time estimate for completion. Some of its algorithms rely on rewriting an expression in various ways; it is possible for this procedure to never terminate if the resulting expressions become more complex instead of less.

In the specific example, factoring the expression and solving individual factors helps.

```
factors = expr.factor().args
solve(factors[4], x)   # "4" by trial and error
```

returns

```
[(c*(-2*a*e + d) - sqrt(c*(16*a**2*c**2*f - 4*a*c*d*e - 4*a*c*f + a*e**2 + c*d**2)))/(2*a*c*(4*a*c - 1)),
 (c*(-2*a*e + d) + sqrt(c*(16*a**2*c**2*f - 4*a*c*d*e - 4*a*c*f + a*e**2 + c*d**2)))/(2*a*c*(4*a*c - 1))]
```