# Exception Thrown error using solve() function in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve an equation in python using this code:

```
import math
from math import *    # cos, sin, asin, sqrt, radians, pi, tanh, log, exp
import time
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve

m = 0.2; d = 0.08; A = 0.25*math.pi*(d**2); g = 9.80665; Cd = 0.47; P = 1.145; H = 15; Vdr = 5; Vwx = 1; Vwz = 1;
t = symbols('t')
y = Eq(((m/(A*Cd*P))*log(-exp(A*H*Cd*P/m)*(tanh(((0.5/m)*sqrt(2*A*Cd*P*g*m)*t)**2-1)))), 0)
tHit = solve(y, t)
print("t =", tHit)
x = (2*m/(A*Cd*P))*log(1+(0.5*A*Cd*P/m)*(Vdr+Vwx)*tHit)
z = Vwz*tHit
print("x =", x, "   z =", z)
```

After some long minutes I'm getting the Exception Thrown error on the line using the `solve()` function.
Anyone knows what can be the reason? I don't have much experience in python, so if there's something wrong with the code, I would like to know.
Thanks

** EDIT **
So I finally fixed the code, it's working now:

```
import math
from math import * 
import time
import sympy
from sympy import *

m = 0.2; d = 0.08; A = 0.25*math.pi*(d**2); g = 9.80665; Cd = 0.47; P = 1.145; H = 15; Vdr = 5; Vwx = 1; Vwz = 1;
t = Symbol('t')
y = (m*sympy.log(-sympy.exp((A*Cd*H*P)/m)*(sympy.tanh((0.5*t*(2*A*Cd*P*g*m)**(1/2))/m)**2 - 1)))/(A*Cd*P)
print("y =", y)
tHit = nsolve(y, t, 0)
print("t =", tHit)
x = (2*m/(A*Cd*P))*log(1+(0.5*A*Cd*P/m)*(Vdr+Vwx)*tHit)
z = Vwz*tHit
print("x =", x, "   z =", z)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! First of all, please provide what kind of exception is thrown. This really matters. Then, provide whole code, along with imports you did, because we don't know what is Eq and what is solve(), we don't know what libraries are you using.

Comment: Hi, edited the post and added the libraries I use. About the exception error - there are no details about this error at all (I'm using Visual Studio). Just this little block popping besdies the `tHit = solve(y, t)` line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exception in this code. It just never ends. I run this code for some time and it never finished. Memory, however, was increasing until took all available memory.

Are you sure this equation can be solved using sympy? Maybe it's algorithms are not effective on such equation?

Unfortunately sympy doesn't have estimation for completion ([Estimating progress of SymPy functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706723/estimating-progress-of-sympy-functions)) so you can at this point:

1. Try solving this in other software (Wolfram Alpha maybe?)
2. Give it more resources and wait
3. Try rewrite equation to other form that may be possible to solve by sympy

Comment: This is my first time using SymPy. Was looking for a way to solve this equation in Python and found this package. I solved this equation in Matlab easily, but needed to convert it to python for my project, so it is solvable but I guess for SymPy it is too much or something? Perhaps you know any other way I can try to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have experience with symbolic math in Python. However, if you solved it in Matlab already, and need it in Python, why not call Matlab routine from Python? I found something like these: https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-and-python.html

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for trying to help me out in this. I just finally managed to make it work. Will add the working code to the post for others. Can close this post afterwards.